# Install node-xmpp-bosh with nodejs on windows

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm new in nodejs word and I use the windows version. I want to install my node-xmpp-bosh server like install instructions

```
 Go to the directory where you want to install 
node-xmpp-bosh (for a local install and move to 
setp-9) or follow step-8

$ cd ~/
$ npm install node-xmpp-bosh
$ node node_modules/node-xmpp-bosh/run-server.js

8. Install globally and run
$ npm install node-xmpp-bosh -g
$ bosh-server
```

but after `$ npm install node-xmpp-bosh`
no installation is done and this is the log file of nmp:

```
     info it worked if it ends with ok
...    
       info node-expat@1.4.4 Failed to exec install script
    ERR! error installing node-expat@1.4.4
    info unbuild C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh\node_modules\node-expat
    verbose from cache C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh\node_modules\node-expat\package.json
    info preuninstall node-expat@1.4.4
    info uninstall node-expat@1.4.4
    verbose unbuild node-expat@1.4.4 [ false,
    verbose unbuild node-expat@1.4.4   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules',
    verbose unbuild node-expat@1.4.4   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\node-xmpp-bosh\\node_modules' ]
    info postuninstall node-expat@1.4.4
    verbose installOne cb node-expat@1.4.4
    verbose about to build C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh
    ERR! error installing node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
    info unbuild C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh
    verbose from cache C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh\package.json
    info preuninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
    info uninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
    verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6 [ true,
    verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules',
    verbose unbuild node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules' ]
    verbose binRoot [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.bin',
    verbose binRoot   { 'bosh-server': './run-server.js' } ]
    info postuninstall node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
    ERR! error rolling back node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node-xmpp-bosh\node_modules\websocket'
    verbose installOne cb node-xmpp-bosh@0.5.6
    ERR! node-expat@1.4.4 install: `node-waf configure build`
    ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
    ERR! 
    ERR! Failed at the node-expat@1.4.4 install script.
    ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
    ERR! not with npm itself.
    ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    ERR!     node-waf configure build
    ERR! You can get their info via:
    ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
    ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    ERR! 
    ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
    ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-xmpp-bosh"
    ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
    ERR! node -v v0.6.11
    ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
    ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    ERR! message node-expat@1.4.4 install: `node-waf configure build`
    ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
    ERR! errno {}
    verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What can I do to resolve this problem 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might help: https://github.com/astro/node-expat/pull/23

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the node-expat module, which node-xmpp-bosh relies on, uses `node-waf`, which is not available on Windows.

Here's some more info: [What is "node-waf" and how to get it on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465248/node-js-what-is-node-waf-and-how-to-get-it-on-windows)

Basically looks like you're out of luck on this unless you manage to build the node-expat native extensions using Visual Studio.

**EDIT:** Someone has compiled more information on alternatives to `node-waf` on Windows here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471319/288425