# Why i can't connect to node-xmpp-bosh server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp

I'm using node-xmpp-bosh serve.I've run run-server.js and a server has been started.When i try to connect to server with converse.js i receive the following error:

> host unknown

In server console appears the same error.Also i've tried to connect with pidgin.In console is the same error

> host unknown

and in pidgin

> The bosh connection manager terminated your session

Any ideas ? I'm running node-xmpp-bosh on windows.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: I have run  run-server.js from https://github.com/dhruvbird/node-xmpp-bosh ...As a client i've tried to connect with pidgin

Comment: Already answered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526855/install-node-xmpp-bosh-with-nodejs-on-windows

Comment: My server is running! I don't have this problem

Comment: Try to run that server and to connect with pidgin to it @VikramChandran

Comment: What's the result @VikramChandran ?

Answer (score 2):

node-xmpp-bosh make a connection between browser and xmpp server.You need to make configuration from config file in node-xmpp-bosh :)